Mirror an Excel Table in the Same Sheet
I have scoured the interwebs trying to find a solution to a seemingly simple task. I have an Excel worksheet that simply contains a table named: ONSITE. This table has columns and rows just like any other table.
I'd like "mirror" this table as a separate table on the same sheet. This is so that when any changes are made to the ONSITE table as far as columns or rows are concerned, the second table is automatically update to contain the same columns and rows.

Name the table and define it using name manager or name box and then use it other cells in the same workbook or sheet. Note that it will return as an array and not as a structured references. or could use Power Query as well here to get a structured reference of a mirrored tabled

To elaborate on Mayukh's point: When you select your table, there's a name on the left side of the ribbon under. if you do a formula as =table1 or whatever the name is, it will create an array that will spill the entire table unformatted as a range automatically. However, you can also query this table and have it export as a table object which you can treat as a table, but you would need to right-click and hit "refresh" for the changes to update.

I can't believe that it was that simple. Using =ONSITE in the cell where I want the "mirror" to be pulls everything over. Is there a way to have it bring the formatting over by chance?

Formatting no way. Unfortunately! For that VBA needed.
